# ¿Cómo recibir array en PHP desde Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Estoy guardando los id de los valores seleccionados en select multiple, los guardo en un input invisible, esto para posteriormente enviarlos al servidor e insertarlos en una tabla.

De la siguiente forma capturo los id de las opciones seleccionadas y las guardo en el input:

```
<script>
    $("#indices").click(function(){
        var selectedValues = [];    
        $("#indices :selected").each(function(){
            selectedValues.push($(this).val()); 
        });
    $('#recibeindice').val(selectedValues); //Aca envio los valores a un input hidden
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Luego en este *Ajax* recojo los valores para después enviarlos al *PHP*, hasta el momento va todo bien, acá llegan todos lo valores del input, pero al hacer el *insert* en el *PHP* solo me inserta el primero.

```
var fila; //captura la fila, para editar o eliminar
    //submit para el Alta y Actualización
    $('#formFichaDocumento').submit(function(e){                         
        e.preventDefault(); //evita el comportambiento normal del submit, es decir, recarga total de la página
        insper_id = $.trim($('#insper_id').val());   
        tipdoc_id = $.trim($('#tipdoc_id').val());    
        doc_numero = $.trim($('#doc_numero').val());
        doc_antecedente = $.trim($('#doc_antecedente').val());    
        doc_materia = $.trim($('#doc_materia').val());    
        doc_fecing = $.trim($('#doc_fecing').val());
        doc_fecemi = $.trim($('#doc_fecemi').val()); 
        doc_fecrec = $.trim($('#doc_fecrec').val());  
        usu_id = $.trim($('#usu_id').val());    
        recibeindice = $.trim($('#recibeindice').val()); //ACA RECIBO EL VALOR DEL INPUT
       

            $.ajax({
              url: "../includes/crudfichadocumento.php",
              type: "POST",
              datatype:"json",    
              data:  {doc_id:doc_id, insper_id:insper_id, tipdoc_id:tipdoc_id, 
              doc_numero:doc_numero, doc_antecedente:doc_antecedente, doc_materia:doc_materia, 
              doc_fecing:doc_fecing, doc_fecemi:doc_fecemi , doc_fecrec:doc_fecrec, 
              usu_id:usu_id, recibeindice:recibeindice, opcion:opcion},    
              success: function(data) {
                tablaFichaDocumento.ajax.reload(null, false);
               }
            });                 
        $('#modalCRUD').modal('hide');                                                          
    });
```

El problema esta en que cuando recibo en el *PHP* para poder hacer el *insert* solo me guarda el primer id seleccionado y necesito guardar todos los que el usuario selecciono, no se cual será la forma de recoger los datos en este caso, pero así lo hago:

```
$recibeindice = (isset($_POST['recibeindice'])) ? $_POST['recibeindice'] : '';
```

Acá están los *insert*, el primero es donde inserto todos los datos del documento y rescato el id del documento para luego hacer el siguiente *insert* a la tabla *indices_del_documento*.

```
switch($opcion){
        case 1:
            $consulta = "INSERT INTO documentos (doc_id, tipdoc_id, doc_numero, doc_antecedente, 
            doc_materia, doc_fecing, doc_fecemi, doc_fecrec, usu_id, insper_id) VALUES('$doc_id', 
           '$tipdoc_id', '$doc_numero', '$doc_antecedente','$doc_materia', NOW(), '$doc_fecemi', 
           '$doc_fecrec', '$usu_id', '$insper_id') ";               
            $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
            $resultado->execute(); 
            $last_id = $conexion->lastInsertId();  
         
            $consulta = "INSERT INTO indices_del_documento (doc_id, ind_id) VALUES('$last_id', 
            '$recibeindice') ";         
            $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
            $resultado->execute();
```

Comment: puedes realizar un `foreach` para recorrer el arreglo que envías y así poder insertar los demás valores, pero también veo que puede haber un problema con tu función de seleccionar los índices. ¿ porque reinicias cada vez la variable `selectedValues`?.

Comment: puede hacer un: `console.log(recibeindice)` antes de `$.ajax` y nos dices que te sale??

Comment: el console.log me muestra los id seleccionados correctamente

Comment: Tu pregunta está planteada de una forma muy confusa. **¿Si haces un `var_dump($_POST);` en el servidor te salen todos los datos que realmente esperas?** Empieza verificando por ahí, y dinos si estás recibiendo los datos esperados, cuales son esos datos y qué intentas hacer con ellos. Pulsa en [edit] y agrega el resultado del `var_dump`.